# Excel cannot find DLL

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have an excel VBA macro that calls a function in a C++ DLL.
The declaration is

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Function XXXX Lib "xxxx.dll" (...
```

This has worked for years, but on some new computers, it fails with the message

```
“xxxx.dll not found”.
```

The DLL is in the current folder. I checked with CurDir() and the current folder is correct.
I have a C++ test program that calls the DLL and it succeeds so there are no missing dependencies.
If I add the folder to the PATH environment variable, it will succeed.
According to all the documentation I found, Excel will always look in the current folder for DLLs.

Any ideas would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: *Excel will always look in the current folder for DLLs* is incorrect. Excel will look for DLLs in the folder where Excel.exe is located, and then in directories that are on the PATH. See the documentation for the Win32 API function *LoadLibrary* for details about how the search is conducted.

Comment: I've seen this before. Adding the full file spec seems to fix it... and then after saving and closing Excel and restarting you should be able to delete the "C:\...\" and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I reread the spec and Ken you are right, it does not say that it searches the current path. It has worked for many years though and with the latest release of Excel works sometimes. Hardcoding paths is not an option as this spreadsheet will be released to many users. I did not want to make changes to the code, but in the end I found no other solution and now call AddDllDirectory() at startup.